# Add additional button to login form

Tags: forms, hooks, users

```
Drupal 7
```

I am trying to add a new button or link to my log in form. The button would simply link to another page outside of the drupal framework. I am looking at the `form_alter` hook but I am not sure if I completely understand how to implement my update.

do I have to update the template.php page?

The form is the login form on the front page. Any help would be great.

I am pretty sure I need something like the following :

```
<?php
$form['preview'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('Preview'),
  '#weight' => 19,
);
?>
```

But I need to add the link. request.php to the button so when clicked it will go to request.php. Also I am not sure where to add this code and how to direct it to my log in form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot alter a form from a theme's template.php file. You need to [create a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/361112) for that. In this module, you can alter the login form in an implementation of the [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) [hooks](http://drupal.org/node/292).

Without some JavaScript, you will not be able to submit the form to a separated URL. What you can do, in your module, is to provide an dedicated [validation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#validate) or [submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) handler for you button. In this handler, you can redirect to your external URL using [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).

Something like:

```
MODULE_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['foo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Foo'),
    '#submit' => array('MODULE_user_login_foo_submit'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
  );
}

MODULE_user_login_foo_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_goto('/path/to/request.php', array('external' => TRUE));
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. Do you know of any clear resource on accomplishing this? There is a lot of great documentation on drupal.org but not much in the way of implementation. Thanks +1

Comment: Thats great but when I click the form tells me I need to enter something into the name and password fields (even though they are not getting used)  I tried adding:   $form['user_login_block']['pass'] = array(
    '#required' => FALSE
  );

  $form['user_login_block']['name'] = array(
    '#required' => FALSE
  );

Comment: Add '#limit_validation_errors' => array() to the button.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This worked perfectly. I am going to have to spend some more time with hooks!